# Serializing Form to Array For ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

For some reason I can not get ServiceStack to serialize posted (serializeArray) form data. 
The json posted is:

```
{"somestuff":"someData","formInput":[{"name":"1","value":"2"},...]}
```

The jQuery I am using to post my form:

```
var formData = $("form").serializeArray();
            var data = {
                someOtherFields: some data,
                formInput: formData
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/api/location",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == "success") {
                        scope.showForm = false;
                        scope.status = "successfully added message";
                    } else {
                        scope.status = response.message;
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is posting to a ServiceStack Service with a DTO:

```
public class ServiceRequest
{
     other atributes;
     public List<ArraySerializeResult> FormInput { get; set; }
}

public class ArraySerializeResult
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The other attributes are serialized fine but the formInput is serialized to a list with the correct number of elements but all the Name and Value pairs are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SerivceStack is expecting you to [send your complex type](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) formatted in [JSV](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format) not [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

You can either format the request in JSV instead of JSON with something like [JSV.js](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release/latest/js/JSV.js?source=c) from the ServiceStack project or implement your own [Request Binder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) to deserialize the JSON.

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    RequestBinders.Add(typeof (ServiceRequest), (IHttpRequest httpReq) => {
        var myRequest = new ServiceRequest();
        // Deserialize the request here using ServiceStack.Text or whatever you like...
        return myRequest;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add "contentType" option to your ajax request. With content-type "application/json", servicestack can desirialize json arrays

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

so it will look like this

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/api/location",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == "success") {
                    scope.showForm = false;
                    scope.status = "successfully added message";
                } else {
                    scope.status = response.message;
                }
            }
        });
```